# What is the function code to show the exact date and last modified date of publishing the blog in wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have my WordPress website [finance buzz](https://www.financebuzz.net/). I want to show the exact date of publishing the blog not like published 2 days ago or 1 month ago. Also, I want to show the last modified date if any blog posts get edited.

Kindly suggest the function code to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `get_the_date()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/ and `get_the_modified_date()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_modified_date/ are what you're looking for.